# UIGraphics.BeginPDFContext document information

Tags: ios, pdf, xamarin.ios

I'm having trouble supplying PDF document info when calling UIGraphics.BeginPDFContext on MonoTouch. 
I've tried using the overload that takes a CGPDFInfo and the one that takes an NSDictionary, but both crash with a SIGSEGV when I supply any string values, such as the Author.

The following code causes a SIGSEGV:

```
var info = new CGPDFInfo()
{
    AllowsCopying = true,
    AllowsPrinting = true,
    Author = "My Name",// Setting any string property crashes
};
UIGraphics.BeginPDFContext(file, RectangleF.Empty, info);
```

The stack trace is as follows:

> at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) 
>   at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSMutableDictionary.LowlevelSetObject (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject,intptr) [0x00011] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSMutableDictionary.cs:394
>   at MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGPDFInfo.ToDictionary () [0x00033] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/CoreGraphics/CGContextPDF.cs:161
>   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIGraphics.BeginPDFContext (string,System.Drawing.RectangleF,MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGPDFInfo) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIGraphics.cs:99

I've asked the question on the [Xamarin Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/526/cgpdfinfo-sigsegv) as well, but received no answer.

I would like to use the overload of BeginPDFContext that takes an NSMutableData as first parameter, but that requires an NSDictionary for the document info, an I have no idea how to supply values to it that doesn't crash. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you just trying to write to an existing PDF? or create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record: this is a bug in MonoTouch (which has now been fixed).

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8879

Comment: Thanks, I submitted the bug report. Excellent response time!